# Refused connection to a Swordfish Service Registry

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soa

i try to set up a swordfish environment, but i'm failing with setting up the service registry.

the first screenshot below shows the setting of the service registry in the sopera toolsuite.

the second screenshot shows the error message when refreshing the service registry.

so, there was no other configuration, i just installed the toolsuite, and opened the "service registry" view in eclipse, then the error popup, as shown in the screenshot, occurs.

What am i doing wrong? Am i missing something? need help!!

regards
matt

[image: service registry]
[image]

SOLUTION: I found a script which brings up the service registry i needed, so now i can see all services registered at this service registry.

NEXT PROBLEM: as shown in the screenshot below, i got a swordfish server to provide the services. But when publishing the contained feature, i again get the error message regarding a confused connection! So whats wrong now? Are there any Swordfish experts in the stackoverflow universe? ;)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another script which brings up a Swordfish server, so everything's fine now!

Comment: No its not fine, because the rest of the world did not find those scripts, only you did. Please post them...

Answer (score 1):

"Connection refused" implies that there is no process running on the port that you are attempting to connect to.

Are you sure the service you are attempting to connect to is running?

Comment: Ok, i found a script to start the service registry. But another problem occured, as described in the first post!